# Bash find files and display path function

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I'm writing a function in my .bashrc file which helps me find files according to the string which I pass as an argument to the function:

```
# ~/.bashrc
function search {
    find . -iname "*$1*" -printf "%f\n"
}
```

This function is good. It prints out all the files with the given string under the directory I'm in, and also all the files with the same given string in all subdirectories. Only it just prints out each file and not its path.

If I for example have a folder containing some sub-folders and files this function would be so much more helpful if it would print out the path to each file if they are located under any sub-folders.

F.ex. if I have a folder named `Folder/` and a few sub-folders named `whatever_num` and running `search thisandthat` would spit out a list looking something like this:

```
$ search thisandthat
some-file-containing-thisandthat-in-its-filename.ext
whatever_1/path/to/some-file-containing-thisandthat-in-its-filename.ext
whatever_2/path/to/some-file-containing-thisandthat-in-its-filename.ext
```

So my queston is: How can I modify my search function so that it prints out the path to the files I might be searching for?

Thank you!

Comment: @JKB, so how do you suggest I use realpath inside this function?

Comment: Thank you, yes. I will accept my answer below in 20 hours since I went with exactly that solution. Not exactly the same as yours or as acro444's answer. But thanks for the help. It shed a light on my situation for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JKB and to @acro444. Their answers helped me modify my search function. I am posting my answer since I decided to go with a slightly different solution than the once they posted but it's thanks to their contribution:

```
# ~/.bashrc
function search {
    find . -iname "*$1*" -printf "%P\n"
}
```

I do it this way because I don't care about seeing `/home/myusername/...` all the time in front of the rest of the path. I know I am in my `/home/username/somefolder` directory and seeing always `/home/username/.....` for each file that might come up is just too much "noise" I think and unnecessary.

Thank you again for the help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
function search {
    find `pwd` -iname "*$1*" 
}
```

Comment: `find "$PWD"` would be both more efficient (no subshell) and more correct. (Try the other way inside a directory name with spaces!)

Comment: ...also, the `function` keyword isn't valid POSIX -- it's more portable to start your functions with `search() {`

Comment: Non-POSIX shell code in `.profile` would be a concern; not so much in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on POSIX. What is POSIX btw?

Answer (score 1):

Change the find line to:

```
find . -iname "*$1*" -printf "$(pwd)/%P\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The `%P` option was something I didn't know about.

Comment: `$PWD` is more efficient than `$(pwd)` (as the latter spawns a subshell).

Comment: ...that said, it'd be better still to just use `find "$PWD"` and let `find` itself fully-qualify the paths, rather than doing it in the format string. (Also, that way you don't need to use GNU extensions, as `-printf` isn't guaranteed by POSIX).